# How to return parameter while executing command in groovy script

Tags: groovy

I am using groovy script to execute a command. After execution I will get the return code either 0 or 1. On the basis of return code, the file from the directory will get deleted.

So, I want to know that how to save the return code in a variable 
& delete command to delete the file from the directory.

I tried the below code to delete file. Where try is the folder name from which I need to delete the file. But it is not working.

```
'[new File("C:/try/")].each{ it.delete() }'     
'new File("C:/try/check.txt").delete()'
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lacks sufficient information to diagnose the problem. Describe your problem in more detail or include a minimal example in the question itself.

Answer (score 3):

```
def someFileToDelete = ...
def cmd = ...
def process = cmd.execute()
def exitCode = process.waitFor()

if(exitCode == 0) {
   def ret = someFileToDelete.delete()
   println "File $someFileToDelete was${ret?'':' not'} deleted"
}
```

Hope it's pretty self-explanatory.

Comment: But I want to delete file. Not the directory.